# Cloud Firestore: setting security rule based on authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to understand how secure it is a security rule based on authentication, like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have collections where each document is relative to a specific user.

I am using Cloud Firestore only from mobile, both Android and iOS, not from web.

Is there any way for a user to get authenticated outside my mobile apps, and hence going to read or write some other user's documents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to make sure that users cannot read each other's information, you should implement stronger rules than `auth != null`.

For example, these rules make it so you can only read and write the data at `/users/userId` if you are authenticated as `userId`.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      // Anybody can write to their ouser doc
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

This will make it impossible for someone to "get authenticated outside my mobile apps, and hence going to read or write some other user's documents" as you mentioned.

Comment: The code snippet above is missing a closing bracket. }

Comment: @SamStern thanks,i tried ur code it it really worked well,but how to secure google json file inside android ??if its irrelavant then leaveit